# Jack's final smile

Tags: samurai-jack

In the final scene of the fifth season.

**Why does Jack smile when he sees the bug in his hand?**

I know this is a reference to the chapter where Ashi understands that Jack is good, but he could not see her, then the bug can not make him remember her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smile could potentially signal to the audience a connection between Jack and Ashi, but we have no reason to assume that Jack's smile had anything to do with Ashi.

This could simply be an instance of in-universe perspective vs audience perspective.  What that smile and that bug represents to us could be completely different to what they represent to Jack.

As to why Jack smiled, consider this (admittedly speculative) answer.  Jack has an immense appreciation for life.  He has spent his entire life fighting a dark force that threatened all life on Earth.  Aku had, for most of Earth's natural history, been a source of pain and misery and death.

That bug, to Jack, could represent so much more than just a bug.  It is a living thing.  A thing that survived the evil that is Aku.  It would not be the first time we have seen Jack quietly appreciating the sanctity of life (just look at how he reacted to the mountain goats).